# Re sizing an image in imageView

Tags: android, imageview, aspect-ratio

I want to define maxHeight for an image that it's adjustViewBounds has been set to true.
in this way adt automatically keeps aspect ratio.
is there any way to gain this approach without keeping aspect ratio?

this is the image, and i want to stretch it from sides, without being displaced:

[image: this is the image, and i want to stretch it from sides, without being displaced]

Comment: It's not clear. Do you want to scale your image without keeping the aspect ratio? I.e.: do you want to stretch your image?

Comment: yes, it's somehow stretching it from sides.

Comment: Via code or in the xml layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/your image name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Comment: this one does the stretch, but is there any way stretch a bit?!

Comment: if u want full screen try this...  android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: If u want to stretch to particular distance.. please use android:layout_width="200dp" change the value, based on that ur image view will change

Answer (score 0):

I think `android:scaleType="fitXY"` is what you are looking for.

Comment: can you explain it?what is this for?

Comment: It will fill your layout such as background

Comment: This is to set as an ImageView parameter.
The ScaleType parameter is "Options for scaling the bounds of an image to the bounds of this view."
More informations here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html